# Is there a JAVA FX 2.0+ runtime for windows mobile

Tags: java, javafx, windows-mobile-6.5

The newest version of the JavaFX runtime that I could find is the 1.3 Early Access. The JavaFX 2.2 SDK does not have a mobile profile. Does this mean that Java FX on mobile has been killed off before it ever got out of Early Access ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the mobile profile is planned for a future release. AFAIK it hasn't been communicated yet, which platforms Oracle will support.

Answer (score 0):

Today JavaFX 2+ is [targeted](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/system_requirements/jfxpub-system_requirements.htm) at desktop/notebook OSes only - no official word (yet) on mobile support.

The closest mobile experience you could get is probably running JavaFX 2+ on a [Windows 7 tablet](http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/tablet-pcs/XE700T1A-A01US).

For JavaFX roadmap information:

- See the [official JavaFX roadmap](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/roadmap-1446331.html).
- See also this [JavaFX faq](http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/02/23/most-often-asked-questions-about-javafx/) by a JavaFX team member.
- See point 5 of [2012 JavaFX Resolutions](http://fxexperience.com/2012/01/2012-javafx-resolutions/) where it mentions embedded operation (which *I think* is Oracles broad grouping of phone/tablet deployments).

Items on the roadmap include:

> **Multi-Touch and Gestures Support**
>
> JavaFX will provide full support for multi-touch and gestures to better meet requirements for
>   touch-enabled displays in desktops, tablets, and embedded devices.
>
> **Sensor Support**
>
> JavaFX will incorporate support for on-device sensors, including accelerometers, gyroscopes and geo-location.

*The following information is based on speculation, not fact.*

Providing a Java API to thoroughly support a variety of mobile platforms requires a great deal more than just JavaFX support.  I think it likely that Oracle will provide:

- An updated version of the [Connected Device Configuration](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/java-me-overview-402920.html) for modern mobile OSes based on a standard (not micro-edition) Java runtime.
- Tools to package [jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/) modularized builds of Java + JavaFX + CDC Mobile OS specific extensions + Your App for target OSes.
- Ways to hook into the native OS libraries to do stuff which is difficult on a standard Java platform.
- Support for Windows Phone, Windows 8 Tablets, iOS and Android/Linux variants as deployment targets.

I think it unlikely that the new platform would support older runtimes such as Windows Mobile 6.5- and Symbian. I have no concrete information that any of the above would actually be done and relying on anything other than the current official roadmap for substantial critical development work would be foolhardy.