# JavaFX2 and Oracle's plans about mobile operating systems

Tags: mobile, javafx-2

I'm writting diploma work about JavaFX 2.0, and I need some information about further growth of this technology. I thought it will be super-multi-platform, but after googling I little disappointed: there are a lot of problems with iOS and android, also in the roadmap of JavaFX there are information only about desktop OSs... So, can developers expect some progress of technology in mobile direction? Will JavaFX be desktop-oriented or wide-universal technology? Or, maybe, it will be some special branch "Mobile JavaFX2"? If JavaFX don't support mobile phones development, Oracle will haven't modern and competitive technology for this huge area of developing?... I really need some answers! Thanks!)

Comment: [This announcement](http://fxexperience.com/2013/02/february-open-source-update/) (you need to read after the first table) is about open-sourcing the iOS and android versions of JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there are a lot of problems with iOS and android

There are no problems but one - iOS and Android are not supported in the current (JavaFX 2.1) version.

> can developers expect some progress of technology in mobile direction?

Not until it is in the public roadmap (which it is not today).

Answering your other questions would just be speculation on the part of anybody who does not know Oracle's private plans.  If you are interested in speculation, you can find some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10229631/is-there-a-java-fx-2-0-runtime-for-windows-mobile/10236801).

Comment: Thanks! I read that there are some "political" problems between Apple and Oracle: Apple don't want to support JavaFX on their iOS, kind of the problem with Flash.

Answer (score 2):

If you asked the same question three years ago i would say that javafx has a bright future. Same thing for Silverlight and Adobe Air or flex.

Today i would say just a single word... HTML5

Java will always try to find a seat on the client side... Adobe sucks because they abandoned their flex developers few months ago and who says that it will not happen again with Air?... Microsoft still tries to convince us that silverlight is a good tech while on the other side they promote ASP.NET with ajax capabilities as their main weapon.

See how fast the browsers are struggling to comply with HTML5 (future!!!) standards and you will agree with me that the above technologies were born obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a direct answer to your question, but i hope it might point you in an alternative direction

Adobe air is architectually very simalar to java. It also runs on a vm on multiple platforms such as windows, osx, and ... Android and IOS. And it's gui's are sexy ... Real eye candy. For mobile there are some considerations, but currently it is the best cross platform language for gui building in my opinion. Not for server side though. But it integrates like a dream with a java server by means of blazeDS or LCDS.

I know that apple has restrictions as set out by their terms and conditions that you are not allowed to run your app in a virtual machine. So adobe had to compile the entire air app as a native application that basically includes the entire air framework. My guess is that oracle is facing similar issues, and that is probably why it is taking some time to roll out

Having fxml with the power of the java language, definately something worth while waiting for and looking forward to it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 5 has no future.. this tool has lot of problems of it's own..HTML 5 can't be used to develop enterprise applications, it is very difficult to code,debug and maintain which is very important for any long term projects on other hand JAVAFX 2 is on the rite track of creating GUI with use of object oriented concepts which makes java developers to easily code,debug and maintain without any hustle..

Comment: This is more a rant than an answer, plus it does not answer the original question.