# running java swing application on windows 8 tablet

Tags: java, swing, windows-8

i have a **java swing** application which work perfectly well on windows 7 computer and i am sure it should work on a windows 8 computer(right?)

How would i port this application so that it runs on a Windows 8 tablet, like the Microsoft surface tablet, can swing applications run on windows 8 tablets

Comment: JavaFX added touch event support in 2.2.  You might want to consider looking into it.  Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10236801/643500

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as i know the only way to create a metro style application for Windows 8 is using WinRT and the only supported environment for now is .NET, so at the moment Swing applications can run only in the desktop app of Windows 8, but they are not "app" and they are not seamlessly integrated in the OS, and they can't be deployed through the Microsoft Store .

If as you stated in a comment you don't care to run the application as a real app, but you just want to run the app through the classic desktop, it is enough to buy a tablet with Windows 8 pro and you will able to run the application in the "legacy" mode(older way through Desktop) ...

Comment: Didn't Microsoft mention that they will release the Surface with Windows 8 Pro? So that would make it possible to run on that version of the tablet, if that's true.. maybe lol

Comment: @aleroot i dont care if its not an app but do u think it would work properly as a desktop app on the windows 8 pro tablet

Comment: @aleroot He would have to create like an intermediate metro app or change the interface to use HTML/CSS instead of SWING to work in that environment.